Adjusting Hot Wire with stepper motor
For my diploma project I need to adjust a hot wire with a stepper motor. To get a starting position for the motor I let the motor move the wire upwards until it hits a button. Then it should stop and set the point it stopped at to the starting position. With the following code the motor just moves upwards and only stops when it hits the 100000 i set to just continously move it upwards and not when the button is pressed. Both motor and button have been tested seperatly and both work fine. Do you have any suggestions or ideas what can be improved or changed in the code?
Thanks for you help!
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// Define stepper motor connections
#define STEP_PIN 14
#define DIR_PIN 12

// Define button pin
#define BUTTON_PIN 4

// Create a new instance of the AccelStepper class
AccelStepper stepper(1, STEP_PIN, DIR_PIN);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Set button pin as input
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);

  // Set stepper motor speed and acceleration
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(500);
  stepper.setAcceleration(200);

  // Set initial position
  stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);
}

void loop() {
  // Check for button press
  int switchState1 = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);

  // If button is pressed, stop the stepper motor and set position to 0
  if (switchState1 == HIGH) {
    stepper.stop();
    stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);
  } else {
    // If button is not pressed, move the stepper motor
    stepper.moveTo(10000); // Adjust the value as per your requirement
    stepper.run();
  }
}


Tested both seperately, i dont have a clue how i should write the code otherwise

How exactly is the button connected to your board?  Do you perhaps need to enable the pull-up resistor on the button pin?

You should also debounce the button.
